# How can I merge 2 maps in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary

If I have 2 Haskell Maps, for example:

```
[("a",1),
 ("b",2),
 ("c",1)]
```

and

```
[("a",1)]
```

How can I write a function in such a way that it would give something like:

```
[("a",2),("b",2),("c",1)]
```

Until now I could only write the base cases but that was all.

Comment: Looks like you need `unionWith` from `Data.Map`: `unionWith (+) map1 map2`.

Comment: If you are implementing a bag, consider just using the [multiset](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset) package.

Comment: For those looking for how to combine maps of different value-types, the functions in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Map-Merge-Strict.html let you e.g. zip values of matching keys with `ziptersect = merge dropMissing dropMissing (zipWithMatched (\_key x y -> (x, y)))` (or change `dropMissing` to some other `WhenMissing` tactic if you want something other than intersecting zips)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about `unionWith` from [`Data.Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Map.html)?

Here's a sample GHCi session using it on two maps `m1` and `m2` both containing the key 'a':

```hs
Prelude> import qualified Data.Map as Map
Prelude Data.Map> let m1 = Map.fromList [('a', 1)]
Prelude Data.Map> let m2 = Map.fromList [('a', 2), ('b', 10)]
Prelude Data.Map> Map.unionWith (+) m1 m2
fromList [('a',3),('b',10)]
```

---

If you want to define your own function to wrap all that up:

```hs
mergeMap :: (Ord k, Num a) => Map.Map k a -> Map.Map k a -> Map.Map k a
mergeMap = Map.unionWith (+)
```

which is the same as

```hs
mergeMap a b = Map.unionWith (+) a b
```

or even

```hs
a `mergeMap` b = Map.unionWith (+) a b
```

---

**Note:** in real life, make sure to make the right choice between lazy and strict maps, and hence between [`Data.Map.Strict.unionWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#g:9) and [`Data.Map.Lazy.unionWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#g:9).

Comment: Thanks very much. And should the function looks something like this:              bagSum :: M.Map String Int -> M.Map String Int -> M.Map String Int
bagSum b1 b2 = M.unionWith (+) b1 b2

Comment: And should the call be mergeMap [("a",1),("b",2)] [("a",1),("b",2)] ??? It says that it couldn't bind the variables

Comment: You're calling it with lists not maps; if you wrap your list literals with `Map.fromList`, it'll work just fine. Like this: `mergeMap (Map.fromList [("a",1),("b",2)]) (Map.fromList [("a",1),("b",2)])` or `Map.fromList [("a",1),("b",2)] \`mergeMap\` Map.fromList [("a",1),("b",2)]`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `Map` is `sort`. This version assumes each key occurs only once in each list. If that's not the case, you could fix it up, but the `Map` approach would start looking a lot more attractive.

```
combine op xs ys = cs op (s xs) (s ys)
  where
    s = sortBy (compare `on` fst)

    cs _ [] qs = qs
    cs _ ps [] = ps
    cs op pss@(p@(pk,pv):ps) qss@(q@(qk,qv):qs) =
      case compare pk qk of
        LT -> p : cs op ps qss
        GT -> q : cs op pss qs
        EQ -> (pk, pv `op` qv) : cs op ps qs
```

Comment: @ErikAllik, it's admittedly a bit hard to say for sure--we are reasoning from a single example. I imagined the lists were intended to represent maps already, and that they needed only be merged. It's possible they're even supposed to be sorted already.